Manage stripe subscriptions with trials and promotion codes
I am building a subscription based SaaS product using Next.js, Supabase and Stripe.
So far it is working but I am struggling getting the right payment workflow.
I am offering two types of subscriptions: monthly - 5€, and yearly 50€. This is modelled as one Product with two Prices.
Both plans have full access to all app features, the only difference is how much they save after one year.
I want to offer a 30 days trial period to both plans. After the 30 days trial ends, the subscriptions becomes active into one of the two plans selected.
I use webhooks to update the database in Supabase, where I store products, prices, customers, subscriptions and users, following the official template.
I currently have two promotion codes, that can be applied to either plan at any time (during trial period or active subscription):

Free forever: for close people I want to give away the app
X months for free: for potential testers that would use the app and give feedback

The current workflow goes like this:

On the /register page, the user selects one of the plans. I store the priceId in the url, and then display the sign up form (just email and password).
When the user signs up, I silently create a customer and subscription using stripe API, which then triggers events that store these in my database. The subscription is created using the selected price plan and a trial period of 30 days. No payment details are required since I created everything under the hood.
At any point in the /account/billing page, the user can apply one of the existing promotion codes. They can also access their customer portal to add their payment details.

Here is where I don't seem to find a proper way to handle things with my knowledge of the stripe API.

If the user applies the "free forever" promotion code, I end the trial immediately and start a "yearly" subscription with the redeemed coupon. This works.
If the user applies the "X months for free", things get more complicated. Ideally, I would like to push the next (or first, if trialing) payment "as many months" as the promotion code entitles. I did not find a way to do this, since I can not modify current_period_end or billing_cycle to an arbitrary value.

The closest I got for this case is by using "subscription schedules": I create a schedule in two phases:

First phase: X months for free with the coupon applied, starting when on trial_ends (if trialing), or current_period_end (if active)
Second phase: once the X months have passed, fallback to the selected price plan and charge accordingly.

This approach seems to work but things get messy if the user chooses to change plans during the first phase. There's a work around (intercepting the subscription.update event and updating the data accordingly), but I think this would overcomplicate things.
Another approach would be to change/extend trial period, but I'd prefer having a clear line between users trialing vs users on an active subscription with a coupon.

Should I change the current workflow?
Is there a better way to implement it?
Is there any other way to push the "next payment" X months when a coupon is used?

export const addPromoCode = async (code: string) => {
  const annualPriceId = PRICES.ANNUAL;
  const monthlyPriceId = PRICES.MONTHLY;

  let coupon = undefined;

  try {
    coupon = await getPromoDetails(code);
  } catch (error: any) {
    return { status: FORM_STATUS.ERROR, message: error.message };
  }

  const {
    percent_off,
    id: couponId,
    duration,
    duration_in_months,
  } = coupon || {};

  const isFreeForever = percent_off === 100 && duration === "forever";

  const { id, trial_end, current_period_end, customer } =
    await createOrRetrieveSubscription(
      isFreeForever ? annualPriceId : monthlyPriceId
    );

  if (isFreeForever) {
    await stripe.subscriptions.update(id, {
      discounts: [{ coupon: couponId }],
      trial_end: "now",
    });
  } else if (duration_in_months) {
    await stripe.subscriptionSchedules.create({
      customer: typeof customer === "string" ? customer : customer.id,
      start_date: trial_end || current_period_end,
      end_behavior: "release",
      phases: [
        {
          items: [{ price: monthlyPriceId, quantity: 1 }],
          iterations: duration_in_months,
          billing_cycle_anchor: "phase_start",
          proration_behavior: "none",
          discounts: [{ coupon: couponId }],
        },
        {
          items: [{ price: monthlyPriceId, quantity: 1 }],
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  revalidatePath(LINKS.BILLING);

  return {
    status: FORM_STATUS.SUCCESS,
    message: "Promo code applied successfully!",
  };
};


There isn't a more elegant solution to this unfortunately. The workflow you've built using Subscription Schedules API is the most elegant way to handle this usecase.

Thanks, that is good and bad at the same time. It is good to know it;s on the right track, but it means I will have to manage the change of subscription manually, updating the subscription schedules accordingly.
